# sublime text 3 js code completion not working after installing angularJS

Tags: angularjs, sublimetext3, code-hinting

I just installed angularJS package control after following the link http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/using-the-angularjs-package-for-sublime-text, this enabled me to get the angular code hints but it messed up my default code hinting feature in sublime-text 3. In the attached image, I have this function `decrementCountdown` defined, when I try to use it - it does not show up in the code completion hints, the only things I see is the AngularJS methods.

[image]

> Could someone please help me? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try disabling AngularJS javascript Autocompletion
as can be seen in the issue on their Github Page.

[Sublime 3 javascript Autocompletion not working properly](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/solved-st3-auto-complete-not-working-with-javascript/10504/5)